# Is it possible to have ubuntu docker container without systemd

Tags: ubuntu, debian, docker, systemd

I figure out that many packages installations are calling systemd to start their software. The problem is that if you want to install the software inside a docker, it will make fail the installation. Because by default Debian makes installation fail if there is a failure inside a post-install script.

Elasticsearch team [did a workaround](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/9f1229ca6e0292049924aaeeeb9f127508ab5d73#diff-536bc7846f9c2dd3e37e1558f07e65c5R56) for that (I'm not sure they understand that it fixes for docker users). But it's a problem for many packages.

Is there a way to make them work anyway inside a debian/ubuntu docker?

Comment: How about building your app in a docker container that runs systemd?

Comment: It's not possible to run systemd, because it can't be start as pid 1 in a docker.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer, there is no good answer as I understand.

But here is what to do:

1. Install software by yourself
2. Send a patch to the package maintainer with this correction

```sh
systemctl daemon-reload || true
# instead of
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Whatever is called after `systemctl`, you should suggest to add `|| true` in case there is this kind of call on post install script of your package. This fixes 2 cases:

1. It's possible that `systemctl` is masked.
2. It's possible `systemctl` does not work (because it's not started as 1st pid) like in dockers.